# Jmeter : random number with beanshell

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I want to add 2 kind of parameters to a post request.

From an http request I extract 2 list of variables:

```
Order_id = input type="hidden" name="(drag.+?)" value="(\d+?)"

Weight_id = class="draggableviews-weight form-select" id=".+?" name="(drag.+?)"
```

In the Post Request that follows, I need to repost all this variables. I use a `BeanShell PreProcessor` for this. The first list is no problem, since this get the same value. The second list should get a new random value between -50 and 50. I also want a different random value for each iteration.

How should I do this ?

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]

If I use Random Variabele Config Element I get the same random int for each variabele. I want a different one for each iteration.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maQeP.png)

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using [ThreadLocalRandom.nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt-int-int-) method like

```
sampler.addArgument(name2, String.valueOf(java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(-50, 51)));
```

Don't inline [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Beanshell scripts, either pass them via "Parameters" section and refer via `Parameters` or `args` shorthands or use appropriate code-based substitutions.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T. I've one question: What shall be preferred `java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt()` or the JMeter internal function `__Random()`? Are there rules/best practice when to use which?

Comment: Use JMeter's internal functions where possible, when using scripting pass it via "Parameters" tab. It is OK to use `ThreadLocalRandom` as well, however make sure you are using [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and Groovy language. See [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for details.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve multiple values from single Regular Expression Extractor, we use Templates as follows:

[image]

then refer groups as follows:
[image]

In the image, you can see that `link` is `Reference Name` and there is only match found with the regular expression.

```
number of matches is : link_matchNr
first group value    : link_1_g1
second group value   : link_1_g2
```

Note: The regular expression I tried on is google.com, you can also simulate the same as follows:
[image]

1. Use [Random function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) as follows:

   value2 = ${__Random(-50,50)};

   log.info("valuee2 " + value2);

   2. Use [Random Variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Variable):
      [image]
      then, refer `Output Variable` in Beanshell Preprocessor as follows:

   value2 = vars.get("randomInt");

Comment: what is the error? did you check the value of value2? use log.info("values2 " + value2); in beanshell preprocessor and run. check the value in logs

Comment: 2016/10/21 08:48:59 ERROR - jmeter.config.RandomVariableConfig: maximum() must be > minimum1) 
2016/10/21 08:49:01 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``           int count = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("Order_id_matchNr"));           . . . '' Encountered "}" at line 16, column 9.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. This is wat i get:

Comment: 2016/10/21 08:54:40 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``        int count = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("Order_id_matchNr"));              . . . '' Encountered "}" at line 15, column 9.
 
2016/10/21 08:54:40 WARN  - jmeter.modifiers.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``        int count = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("Order_id_matchNr"));              . . . '' Encountered "}" at line 15, column 9.

Comment: you have to use Template when you capture more than one value (using multiple groups) in Regular Expression Extractor. edited answer

Comment: Extracting more than 1 value is no problem, and works fine now.

Comment: The method with Random Variable Element works , but then i get the same random variabel for each value

Comment: you mean in multiple iterations? or for multiple threads? If for multiple Threads, then set the value "Per Thread(user)?" to "True" and try